# JAVA NullPointException

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces

ao clicar no meu button na view  o parametro não esta chegando no meu atributo java responsavel pelo button

---

```
public Map<String, Object> getFiltroGlobalMap(){
    Map<String, Object> mapFiltrosGlobais = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if (tipoDigitalizacaoFiltroSelect != null) {
        mapFiltrosGlobais.put("tipoDigitalizacao", tipoDigitalizacaoFiltroSelect);
    }
    if (listUnidadeOrganizacionalFiltro != null && listUnidadeOrganizacionalFiltro.isEmpty() == false) {
        mapFiltrosGlobais.put("unidadeOrganizacional", listUnidadeOrganizacionalFiltro);
    }
    if(dataVencimentoInicioFiltro != null){
        Uteis.zeraHoraData(dataVencimentoInicioFiltro);
        mapFiltrosGlobais.put("dataVencimentoNotaInicio", dataVencimentoInicioFiltro);
    }
    if(dataVencimentoFimFiltro != null){
        Uteis.setUltimaHoraData(dataVencimentoFimFiltro);
        mapFiltrosGlobais.put("dataVencimentoNotaFim", dataVencimentoFimFiltro);
    }
    if(dataAprovDiretorInicioFiltro != null){
        Uteis.zeraHoraData(dataAprovDiretorInicioFiltro);
        mapFiltrosGlobais.put("dataAprovDiretorInicio", dataAprovDiretorInicioFiltro);
    }
    if(dataAprovDiretorFimFiltro != null){
        Uteis.setUltimaHoraData(dataAprovDiretorFimFiltro);
        mapFiltrosGlobais.put("dataAprovDiretorFim", dataAprovDiretorFimFiltro);
    }
    if(!StringUtils.isBlank(getFiltroIsMei()) && getFiltroIsMei() !=null){
        mapFiltrosGlobais.put("filtroIsMei",getFiltroIsMei().equals("SIM")?Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    return mapFiltrosGlobais;
}
```

[image: modo debug, não esta passando pela minha variavel]

[image: código xhtml do meu button, que manda a resposta para o lado java]

Comment: ao  clicar no button boolean na view  ele não esta chegando ao meu atributo java para pegar a informação.

Answer (score 0):

Vc fez o submit do form que está esse `selectOneButton`? Só o ato de clicar no `selectOneButton` não submete o form, a não ser que vc coloque alguma função ajax no mesmo.

Segue um exemplo de implementação desse componente:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
    <h:outputText value="Platform:" />
    <p:selectOneButton value="#{selectOneView.option}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS4" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii U" itemValue="Wii U" />
    </p:selectOneButton>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:spacer />

    <h:outputText value="Selected:" />
    <h:outputText id="display" value="#{selectOneView.option}" style="font-weight: bold" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

View:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;


@ManagedBean
public class SelectOneView {

    private String option;

    public String getOption() {
        return option;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }
}
```